# Spring Bean Creation at Runtime

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to create beans at runtime by using the @Configuration and the @Bean annotations. The reason for this is I am trying to have Spring be aware of the created beans so that it can handle scheduling for the application I am creating. I've defined the annotated class like so:

```
@Configuration  
public class GathererConfigBean {
    @Bean(name = "FactoryBean")
    public MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean createMethodInvokingJobDetail(String service, Object obj, String method) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException{
        MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactory = new MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean();
        jobDetailFactory.setBeanName(service + "FactoryBean");
        jobDetailFactory.setTargetObject(obj);
        jobDetailFactory.setTargetMethod(method);
        jobDetailFactory.setConcurrent(false);
        jobDetailFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobDetailFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "TriggerBean")
    public CronTriggerBean createTriggerBean(String service, JobDetail job, String schedule) throws ParseException{
        CronTriggerBean trigger = new CronTriggerBean();
        trigger.setBeanName(service + "TriggerBean");
        trigger.setJobDetail(job);
        trigger.setCronExpression(schedule);
        return trigger;
    }

    public CronTrigger createTrigger(String service, JobDetail job, String schedule) throws ParseException{
        return createTriggerBean(service, job, schedule);
    }

    public JobDetail createJobDetail(String service, AbstractGatherer obj, String method) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException{
        return (JobDetail) createMethodInvokingJobDetail(service, obj, method).getObject();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run this I always get the following exceptions and I have been unable to find a similar example of what I am doing on-line. Originally, I had thought it was because they have the same name, but that doesn't seem to be the case because when I just run one I get the same error.

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'FactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/linuxbox/enkive/statistics/gathering/GathererConfigBean.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: : No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'FactoryBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:983)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.linuxbox.enkive.Main.run(Main.java:54)
    at com.linuxbox.enkive.MainJettyWebApps.main(MainJettyWebApps.java:53)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    ... 16 more
Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'FactoryBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:678)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:829)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:983)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.linuxbox.enkive.Main.run(Main.java:54)
    at com.linuxbox.enkive.MainJettyWebApps.main(MainJettyWebApps.java:53)
```

Any help, feedback, ideas, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, and let me know if you need more specific information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use **@PostConstruct** annotation on one of your method that needs to be executed just after the dependency injection is performed. Have a look at this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) to know more about it.

One more way is to make your class implement **ApplicationContextAware** interface to get access to the application context. For more details on it please refer this [link.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/beans.html)

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like spring is having trouble resolving your String parameters for your Bean methods.  Have a look at the [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) where they construct a datasource using JavaConfig.  As the examples suggest you should try using @Qualifier

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("quartz.service.name") String service;
// ...
```

or @Value with a SpEL expression to bind the string params

```
@Value("${quartz.service.name"}) String service;
```

The spring documentation does not provide examples of using `@Autowired @Qualifier` as method parameter annotations with JavaConfig but it should be consistent with constructor autowiring.